# Statement of fundamental theorem of calculus in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I frequently see the following statement for the fundamental theorem of calculus in complex analysis:

Suppose $\gamma$ a path with parameter interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb R$, $F$ defined on an open set containing $\gamma([a,b])$ and $F'(z)$ exists and is continuous at each point in $\gamma([a,b])$. Then
$$
\int_{\gamma([a,b])} F' =  F(\gamma(b)) - F(\gamma(a))
$$

My question:

Why don't just state that $F$ is holomorphic in an open set containing $\gamma([a,b])$ since the continuity of $F'(z)$ in $\gamma([a,b])$ implies that $F'(z)$ exists for all $z$ in an open set containing $\gamma([a,b])$?

**EDIT:**

I'm not trying to bump this question up, but just wanted to say that I realize that at this stage in most text books on Complex Analysis it has not been proved yet that a holomorphic function has continuous derivatives, so from that perspective the usual statement makes sense. That said, I think it would be sufficient to state that $F'(z)$ is integrable (I am a fan of stating the weakest possible assumptions).

Comment: "[S]tating the weakest possible assumptions" does not necessarily make for good pedagogy or textbook writing.

Comment: @TedShifrin I do agree with that, especially for a first reading, but in this particular case I think requiring that $F'$ is integrable  is not much more difficult and/or detrimental to pedagogy than requiring it's continuous. Unless of course the continuity is really necessary (which I don't think it is).

Comment: Undergraduate level complex analysis is based on Rieman integral theory, so usually we assume the integrand is at least piecewise continuous. Moreover, our ultimate goal is to deal with holomorphic functions, which are even analytic, so there's no need for such weak assumption. Later you will see that if $F$ is holomorphic in an open set then so does $F'$.